# Filter Stream (Kafka?) to Dynamic Number of Clients

Tags: apache-kafka, bigdata, apache-nifi

We are currently designing a big data processing chain. We are currently looking at NiFi/MiNiFi to ingest data, do some normalization, and then export to a DB. After the normalization we are planning to fork the data so that we can have a real time feed which can be consumed by clients using different filters.

We looking at both NiFi and/or Kafka to send data to the clients, but are having design problems with both of them.

With NiFi we are considering adding a websocket server which listens for new connections and adds their filter to a custom stateful processor block. That block would filter the data and tag it with the appropriate socket id if it matched a users filter and then generate X number of flow files to be sent to the  matching clients. That part seems like it would work, but we would also like to be able to queue data in the event that a client connection drops for a short period of time.

As an alternative we are looking at Kafka, but it doesn't appear to support the idea of a dynamic number of clients connecting. If we used kafka streams to filter the data it appears we would need 1 topic per client? Which would likely eventually overrun our Zookeeper instance. Or we could use NiFi to filter and then insert into different partitions sort of like here: [Kafka work queue with a dynamic number of parallel consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372210/kafka-work-queue-with-a-dynamic-number-of-parallel-consumers). But there is still a limit to the number of partitions that are supported correct? Not to mention we would have to juggle the producer and consumers to read from the right partition as we scaled up and down.

Am I missing anything for either NiFi or Kafka? Or is there another project out there I should consider for this filtered data sending?

Comment: Kafka does support multiple clients and all clients can send to the same topic, if you configure the producer that way. Filtering can be done by Nifi or Kafka Streams (probably easier with Nifi GUI)

Comment: My understanding was that Kafka streams needed to write to a new topic. Which meant I would have to write a new topic for every client which is unsustainable. Every client will have a different filter, so I can't filter in NiFi and then write out to a single topic for all clients to read from. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you meant.

Comment: Your clients wouldn't be using Kafka Streams, though, they would be using a regular Kafka producer.

Comment: I need the clients to consume filtered subsets of the data, they are not producing data.

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding, then. In that case, if each client has their own filter, then depending on the data, you can have one topic per filter "type". The API for writing out to a another topic is just one method call in Kafka Streams, it's not required, as far as I know. The only alternative I know of is have all the clients consume all the messages, then drop ones they don't care about.